# implement client-side business logic in silverlight on an asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I've heard (on a podcast) about using Silverlight to do client-side validation on an asp.net page. Meaning you have an html page and then you put all the business logic/validations that you would normally put into javascript into Silverlight. However, I'm unable to find any examples of this -- and unfortunately don't know which podcast it was on.

Anyone have a recommendations for resources that I can read that will explain how this is done? No luck googling for it.

Maybe it's not possible or silly? Admittedly, there's a "why not just build a silverlight app" argument. Agreed. But let's shelve that for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to make Silverlight classes JavaScript callable , ie make is scriptable
A  search for scriptable samples will give you loads of blogs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645085(VS.95).aspx
http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2007/06/howto-make-your-silverlight-11.html